# What are some options for embedding Google Maps into a WordPress site?

Tags: google-maps, wordpress

**Background**

A non-technical user would like me to embed a Google Map into a WordPress-powered site. She needs the ability to add markers using a simple mechanism, and to link those markers to pages within the site.

Ideally I (as administrator) would have the ability to

- use Styles on the basemap (eg, don't show roads)
- write JavaScript which controlled map interactions (eg, restrict zooming to just 2 levels)
- access advanced Google Maps functionality (eg, marker clustering)

There is no shortage of [Google Maps plugins for WordPress](http://www.wpmayor.com/1343/plugin-reviews/best-google-maps-plugins-for-wordpress/), so my questions are:

1. Can anyone on GIS.SE recommend any particular plugin?
2. Do any of them allow customised JavaScript to run? (they appear to be aimed a non-GIS
   endusers)

Thanks

Comment: I'm experimenting with [google-maps-v3-shortcode/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-maps-v3-shortcode/) and it seems pretty good. It lacks some of my "wish list" items but does allow easy marker updating via a Fusion Tables document, which my user could easily accomplish

Comment: A simpler option may be to design a stand-alone map using HTML, CSS and JavaScript, and upload it somewhere. Then simply embed it into a WordPress Page using an iFrame. Any reasons why this would be a bad idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Google Map to WordPress site?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19794/how-to-implement-google-map-to-wordpress-site)

Answer (score 2):

it seems you need some level of map behavior customization.
what I suggest is to develop the solution with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), it's a Javascript client mapping framework that let's you:

- you can easily introduce a map inside any web site, wordpress included
- Use Google Maps as base layers (roads, aerials and aerials with labels, switching betweeb them)
- add markers to the map clicking on it, customize markers symbology (for example clustering based on the zoom level)
- restrict and customize map interactions (panning, zooming, etc.)
- and many more things

Hope this helps