# Integrating Google Maps in WordPress?

Tags: google-maps-api, wordpress

I need to add Google Map with about 400 markers into WordPress site (into one page). Every marker needs to have info window with photo, description and link. It is really high number of markers, so I'm not sure what is the best way to implement that kind of map.

What do you suggest?

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/suggestions-for-simple-mapping-platform-for-alumni-web-site) for ideas.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Does your map need to be static (an image to just look at) or interactive?

Comment: Static is fine.

Comment: For a static map just use ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS to author a map and then save it as an image that you can include in your Wordpress site as a picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could give **Leaflet Maps Marker Wordpress Plugin** a try

> Pin, organize & show your favorite places through OpenStreetMap/WMTS, Google Maps/Earth (KML), GeoJSON or Augmented-Reality browsers

http://www.mapsmarker.com/